# Method getDialog null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dialog

I have a problem is NullPointerException when call getDialog():

I have a Progressbar and want to show and hide it when data in fragment changed(i have a fragment and DialogFragment)

I call show progressbar first and hide after, when i show app run properly, it mean getDialog not null, but why after that i hide progressbar getDialog null?

My code:

```
 private RewardVideoAdsUtils.CheckNeedShowVideoAdsListener videoAdsListener = new RewardVideoAdsUtils.CheckNeedShowVideoAdsListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(boolean result) {
        if (result){
            dialogPremiumFeatures.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

            loadVideoRewardAds();

            return;
        }
        gotoCreateBudget();
    }
};
```

method show progressbar

```
 private void loadVideoRewardAds(){
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        dialogPremiumFeatures.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.progressLoaddingVideo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(MoneyConfig.ADS_VIDEO_REWARD_ID, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

method hide progressbar

```
 public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Logger.e(TAG, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded");
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    dialogPremiumFeatures.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.progressLoaddingVideo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and hide progressbar get NullPointerException